# Отключается CSS в письмах Mail.ru

Tags: html, email

Верстаю html-письмо. При отладке вёрстки возникла проблема в почте Mail.ru. Путём некоторых манипуляций я выяснил, что использование вот этого CSS-класса:

```
.footerBye {
    width: 435px;
    color: #757575;
    line-height: 140%;
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

Выключает вообще весь css в письме. Если использую этот класс, письмо приходит вообще без css. Если этот класс убираю, то остальные css-классы отлично загружаются.

Я не могу понять логики почты mail.ru. В этом классе нет каких-то уникальных свойств *(все эти свойства есть и в других классах, которые нормально работают)*. В чём может быть проблема? Mail.ru запрещает называть css-классы footerBye или что?

Comment: У вас значение vertical-align неправильное. Конечно, это не оправдывает mail.ru что он из-за этого зачем-то удаляет вообще все стили, тем не менее если написать правильное значение, то всё начинает работать нормально

Comment: @andreymal большое спасибо! Проблема действительно в этом! Меня смутило то, что в другом классе я тоже использовал vertical-align, но там он никак не влиял на отображение css (на самом деле там он был с правильным значением top, потому и не влиял). Оформите свой комментарий как ответ, я отмечу его решением.

Comment: @Zhenyria, andreymal, в соседнем вопросе писал что уже год как ленится ответы писать, скорее всего вам самим придется оформить ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выяснилось, что почтовый ящик Mail отключает все стили в письме, если указать в css-классе неверное значение `vertical-align` *(у меня было указано `vertical-align: center`, что неверно)*.

Сами Mail никак этот баг не прокомментировали, но сказали, что будут исправлять.